# Timeout thread while it is in a system command

Tags: multithreading, perl, interrupt-handling

I have a seemingly simple problem. I need to execute a series of 
system commands (using backquotes) in parallel.

The code below has been stripped of anything meaningful besides 
demonstrating my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict; 
use threads; 
use POSIX; 
my @threads = (); 
sub timeout { 
  print "TIMEOUT\n"; 
  foreach my $thread (@threads) { 
    $thread->kill("ALRM") if $thread->is_running(); 
  } 
} 

POSIX::sigaction(SIGALRM, POSIX::SigAction->new(\&timeout)); 
alarm(2); 
sub threadsub { 
  sub handletimeout { 
    print "KILL\n"; 
    threads->exit(1); 
  } 
  POSIX::sigaction(SIGALRM, POSIX::SigAction->new(\&handletimeout)); 
  # while(1) { sleep(1); } 
  return `sleep 10`; 
} 

for(my $i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
  push(@threads, thread->create(\&threadsub)); 
} 

foreach my $thread (@threads) { 
  my $res = $thread->join(); 
}
```

Now, the problem is the ALRM signal sent to the threads are never 
caught when the thread is blocked in the system call. If you uncomment 
the while loop the signal are caught as intended. 
How do I make this work so I'm able to timeout my threads even if 
they're stuck in the system command?

Thanks,

Kasper

Comment: As a work around I've now successfully used a condition variable from threads::shared. I can then keep the interrupt handling in the main thread and have this block on a cond_wait instead of the $thread->join(). On timeout I then kill the threads from the main thread using detach on them. I'd still like the above code to work tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **man threads**

```
   Unsafe signals
       Since Perl 5.8.0, signals have been made safer in Perl by postponing their handling until the interpreter is in a safe state.  See "Safe
       Signals" in perl58delta and "Deferred Signals (Safe Signals)" in perlipc for more details.

       Safe signals is the default behavior, and the old, immediate, unsafe signalling behavior is only in effect in the following situations:

       ?   Perl has been built with "PERL_OLD_SIGNALS" (see "perl -V").

       ?   The environment variable "PERL_SIGNALS" is set to "unsafe" (see "PERL_SIGNALS" in perlrun).

       ?   The module Perl::Unsafe::Signals is used.

       If unsafe signals is in effect, then signal handling is not thread-safe, and the "->kill()" signalling method cannot be used.
```

That in-effect tells that signals will be deferred till perl is in un-safe state. If we switch to 'unsafe-signals' program terminates with message **Cannot signal threads without safe signals at threads.pl**. Please check whether **un-safe signals** work in your system. Though it works it is **un-safe**.  Recommend to migrate to processes. The below code should give you desired results.

```
use strict;
use POSIX;

my $pid=fork();

sub timeout {
  print "TIMEOUT\n";
  kill SIGALRM,$pid;
}

if( $pid ) { ## parent
    alarm(2);
    POSIX::sigaction(SIGALRM, POSIX::SigAction->new(\&timeout));
    waitpid $pid,0;
} else { ## child
    sub handletimeout {
        print "SIGALRM child\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    POSIX::sigaction(SIGALRM, POSIX::SigAction->new(\&handletimeout));
    `sleep 10`;
    print "child normal exit";
}
```